# How best to trigger code after each move in optaplanner?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I need to run a calculation into memory at the end of each move and then update the score based on this. The outcome of the calculation needs to be stateful as its referenced elsewhere (stored on the solution).

The documentation suggests this should be a *PlanningEntity* updated as a *ShadowVariable* with a *VariableListener* on the main entity but of course this naturally triggers per entity change, re-calculating unnecessarily.

1. How can this be triggered at the end of the **move**, instead of per **variable**? From Drools? Is that not a hack?
2. If not using a *VariableListener*, it would no longer be a *PlanningEntity*. Isn't making it a *ProblemFact* contrary to the documentation? What's the downside?

Further info:

- The "calculation" is a forecast of values of a flow network over the planning period, where the flow levels are dependent on the current position of tasks.
- We are using real-time planning, so the planning period window adjusts to task set size, and shifts through time.

Comment: What does the calculation represent? If I understand the use case better, I might be able to suggest the best approach or agree if it's an API gap in optaplanner.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet It forecasts values of a flow network over the planning period, where the flow levels are dependent on the placement of tasks that affect the flow. I'll add this to the question.

Comment: You might need to keep a Set of tasks that affect the flow. Just count++ and count-- aren't always correct, for example when swapping something with itself.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet the task has an attribute for whether the flow needs to be recalculated which is checked in the variable listener. So it is only fired for entities its dependent on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Sounds like you should use a shadow variable. Do note you still need a normal constraint too update the score according to that shadow variable's state.

Do note that you can have a shadow entity class that is a singleton (per problem solution) which has a single shadow variable that is updated if any planning entity changes. Use `@PlanningEntityProperty` (without `Collection`) on a `@PlanningSolution` class's field.

At the end of a move, each Move calls `triggerShadowVariableListeners()`, not in the middle. So if you're worried about performance, you shouldn't be.
If you're worried about correctness - because the number of calls affects your calculation - well don't design/implement it that way...

2) ProblemFacts can't change during solving (not counting real-time planning). Not a single field of them. Otherwise it's a PlanningEntity.

0) MoveListener doesn't exist, intentionally (for good reasons), not even internally (even the very internal PhaseLifecycleListener only listens to steps, not moves).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey. This is good because its confirms the decisions I took. I have a singleton PlanningEntityProperty with a shadow variable updated after triggerShadowVariableListeners is called. But if the move changes more than one planning variable (e.g. a swap move, or a custom move affecting more than one entity) does the afterVariableChanged not run multiple times?

Comment: IIRC, it depends on whether `VariableListener.requiresUniqueEntityEvents()` returns true or false.

Comment: I've just checked that and it is false by default. But it doesn't seem to make a difference. Turning TRACE on shows the variable listener firing for each entity moved. Some of my custom moves move a lot of tasks so it should only be fired once. I have seen StatefulVariableListener. Do I need to maintain a state of when a move starts and stops to know to only fire it once somehow?

Comment: Ok I've just tried out the approach above and it works. I maintain a count on the Forecast planning entity. The VariablListener increments this count and drools checks if the count is more than 0. If it is then it recalculates only then. Does that sound like a good approach?

Comment: It works, and performs much better with that approach. Thanks for your help and time Geoffrey.

Comment: Do do a run with FULL_ASSERT to confirm it's safe. Ideally a variable listener shouldn't depend on how many times it's called: each call just looks at the sources that changed and updates its shadows accordingly. See ArrivalUpdatingVariableListener.

Comment: You're right that there's score corruption. Looking at the ArrivalUpdatingVariableListener, its just the same problem isn't it? Its one entity updating a shadow variable for one or more entities. Whereas, in my problem, I need multiple entities to update one entity only once per move. Does that make sense?

Comment: ArrivalUpdatingVariableListener doesn't have score corruption, fwiw. The first event should update that entity and the next events should detect that it's already in the correct state and do nothing.

Comment: No sorry, I meant mine has score corruption, but that I didn't see how the example solved the problem. But how can that be possible? Each source entity could have different effects on the target entity?

Comment: Finally got this working needing to be more careful in ensuring any variable listener correctly updates shadow variables relative to the entity triggering it. But I still managed to reduce complexity by only running the calculation once per move by checking state variables on the shadow entity. Thanks for your help and patience @GeoffreyDeSmet!

Comment: You're welcome. Shadow variables are extremely powerful, but they're not easy to use. Any idea's how we could have made it easier for you?

Comment: Shadow variables are well documented and have good examples for typical use case; when extending on that, the learning curve for experimentation with ideas is steep. Its difficult to know what to ask for help with and not knowing you are on the right track is costly time-wise.

FULL_ASSERT and re-building the idea gradually was key, like custom moves. The error messages are very detailed but require learning underlying behaviour to understand.

Just observations, not criticisms. Optaplanner's core functionality and initial setup is very quick and intuitive.

Comment: Only suggestions i can think of:
1) highlight the concept of a 'shadow entity' more explicitly, encouraging use as acceptable practice.
2) Somehow encourage/enforce use of FULL_ASSERT during development of custom moves, shadow variable etc? Saves time in the long run. Perhaps you should have to override full-assertion per custom move/variable listener once happy it works?

Comment: Good point 1) on document "shadow entity", created issue here: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1780 Not sure if I understand 2) - the default REPRODUCIBLE mode can't sacrifice performance.

Comment: That's great. Regarding 2) I wasn't exactly sure but one idea was to have full assertion be per custom move and variable listener,  and that it is on by default when extending the base classes. A warning could be displayed when running code saying to override this setting once happy that the code is working. This also allows you to toggle it per class when wanting to test only certain changes. It's just an idea really but certainly would have helped me in the initial stages by forcing me to develop with this mode on, and would be quicker than having full assert on for everything :)